# Does LayoutInflater create objects?

Tags: android

I am new to android as you can se.e :) I have a `TableLayout` with 100 `LinearLayout` views inside, and each `LinearLayout` contains my custom view, all in XML.

Now, I know I can access those custom views by IDs. It works this way, but is there a way to access them through the `TableLayout` in code?

I tried using `LayoutInflater` but is seems that it does not instantiate my custom views (the test statements inside the constructor of custom views are not executed). Can someone help? Thanks.

Comment: `I have TableLayout with 100 LinearLayouts in side and each Linearlayout cintains my custom view all in xml` Holy...

Comment: I know but there is no other way to create borders i tablelayout so  each LinearLayoit is 1 pixel wider than the view inside this creates vertical border and i need 10 x 10 grid.

Comment: Margin and padding are concepts that you should look up now :)

Comment: Thanks Benjamin :) my implementation is working now, it was not working because I forgot to use TableRow to access the table layout elements :).

Comment: I might use the margin and padding later on. However I have differetn problem now. My table layout contains custome views (TokenView) object. I draw differetn shapes in them like circel and square. However if in the code I reassigne the existin TokenView to new one eg: ' t = new TokenView() ' the sahpes are not drawn. My walkaound at the moment is that I use existing TokenView that are created with the layout and I am modyfing them in run time. But I wonder why the other method does not work ? maybe that is where I need LayoutInflator ?